# Activii workflow long running task

Tags: activiti

I am using Activti version 6.0.0.

I want synchronous executions of task in activiti,but I have a long running task which might take 20 minutes to execute.
I wanted to get process instance id quickly in my controller without considering completion of task in bpmn,so I added a intermediate timer event of "0 minute" in my bpmn file.

I  have started executing a process,lets say with processInstanceid p1.At that time only I again start the process,lets say with processInstanceid  p2.
Now both processes arrive till the task where there is a wait event of 20 minutes(I have used while loop for this).Now according to the flow both processes should come till the end task and finish their execution but instead of that none of the process finish its execution and run multiple times from first task to end task.

how to run multiple processes independently and parallaly from start task to end task (one of these tasks have code which will take long time to execute)

Answer (score -1):

Likely you tasks are timing out and the the retry logic is kicking in which is causing the multiple run. Ultimately the instances will fail after 3 retries.
To be completely candid, synchronous execution of long running tasks can lead to real problems, especially under load where you can easily exceed available threads, memory or other resources.
You'd be far better served to use an asynchronous model such as documented nicely by Camunda here: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/servicetask/service-invocation-asynchronous

I have successfully used this pattern with all of the Activiti variants and it works nicely.